# Вернуть число без знака минус

Tags: c#

Если в результате окажется число с знаком "-" как его вернуть без знака!?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double t1, t2, t3;

    t1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    t2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

    t3 = t1 + t2;

    if (t3 <= 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        textBox3.Text = String.Format("{0}", t3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Abs() разве модуль числа перестала вычислять?

Comment: Мельчают программисты однако

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте `Math.Abs` и уберите `if`/`else`:

```
t3 = Math.Abs(t1 + t2);

textBox3.Text = String.Format("{0}", t3);
```

Comment: Не плохо было бы посоветовать автору вопроса избавиться от условий после этого.

Comment: @Visman ок, на всякий случай